# IIS 404.4 for rewriting https to http

Tags: iis, https, http, rewrite

I have two servers running IIS, trying to serve Power BI Report Server (if it matters).

As far as I can tell on both servers, I have the following:

- Power BI Report server listening on 127.0.0.1:80 (http)
- IIS listening on (all ips):443 (https)
- IIS pointing at an empty directory to serve
- A rewrite rule that matches `(.*)` and redirects to `http://localhost:80/{R:1}`

All versions of everything as far as I can tell are the same (IIS version 10, Windows server 2016, etc), but things work on one server, and don't on the other. I have also verified that the web.config files on the two servers are the same as well.

The error that I am getting back on the server that doesn't work is a 404.4, which after some research means that there is a missing handler? The actual error I have in the trace logs is that `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`.

How can I fix this issue/figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Mistake 3 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: I did install ARR. Is there a way to check if it is not installed properly/worked?

Comment: Enable FRT to see what's under the hood https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: I did do that, but I am still not sure what I should be looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

For some reason, when I installed ARR, it was not set to enable the proxy (at the machine level, ARR Cache -> Server Proxy Settings -> enable.